# Trigger doesn't work on ToggleButton.IsChecked property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, togglebutton

Here is a simple XAML with trigger that should change ToggleButton content when it is checked. But for some reason it doesn't work. I have a silly feeling that I missed something extra small. Appreciate your help

```
<ToggleButton Content="&lt;">
    <ToggleButton.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ToggleButton">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Content" Value="&gt;" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ToggleButton.Style>
</ToggleButton>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must move `Content="&lt;"` from *`ToggleButton`* to setter of `Style`.

Example:

```
<ToggleButton>
    <ToggleButton.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ToggleButton">
            <Setter Property="Content" Value="&lt;" />

            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Content" Value="&gt;" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ToggleButton.Style>
</ToggleButton>
```

Because local value has *`higher precedence`* order over Style setters and triggers:

1. Property system coercion.
2. Active animations, or animations with a Hold behavior.

   `3. Local value.`
3. TemplatedParent template properties.
4. Implicit style.

   `6. Style triggers.`
5. Template triggers.

   `8. Style setters.`

...

For more information, please see:

[`MSDN: Dependency Property Value Precedence`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

You are overriding the `Content` set by the Trigger by setting the `Content` attribute at the control level. You want to set it using a `Setter` within the Style instead:

```
<ToggleButton>
    <ToggleButton.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ToggleButton">
         <Setter Property="Content" Value="&lt;" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Content" Value="&gt;" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ToggleButton.Style>
</ToggleButton>
```